# Slide Navigation bar away like in Photo viewer of Iphone

Tags: uinavigationbar, slide

does anybody could please explain me, how to slide away the navigation bar in a tableviewcontroller, like the navigation bar of the iphone photo viewer?

It would be great, if anybody has some code for me.

Thanks and regards
Marco

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a UINavigationController, and then this functionality comes almost "for free".
At creation stage, you first create your view controller. Then you create a UINavigationController, passing it your previously created view controller.
Later on, when you want to slide away the navigation bar, you push a new view controller using the pushViewController:animated: function call. Take a look at the code below:

```
// Creation time
// Create your own view controller. below is just an example
UIViewController *myController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

// Now create a navigation controller
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];

// Retain the above somehow, add their view to the Window etc. - not detailed here

// Later, when you want to slide away your controller, you need to push a new view controller. 
// The below code assumes "self" is actually myController which you defined previously:

UIViewController *newController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
// The above line will make the controller and navigation bar slide away, revealing your new controller
```

This is a very rough code sample, which does not include all the details such as memory management etc. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: In which method could I slide away the controller?

Comment: The pushViewController:animated: method is the one which slides a new controller into place (pushing the previous controller out of the screen). When you're done and want to slide back to the initial controller, you should use popViewControllerAnimated: